# With a Word ContentControl DatePicker how do i get the value?

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2010

I have a ContentControl that is a DatePicker in a word document. I'm trying to use it to populate some value in a code behind but I cant seem to get the value out of it.

```
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl, _
    Cancel As Boolean)
```

None of the properties on ContentControl are close to .Value or .Text. I have seen other content controls use:

```
ContentControl.DropdownListEntries(1).Text
ContentControl.DropdownListEntries(1).Value
```

This, as expected for a DatePicker, does not work but it is the only property of ContentControl that returns anything close to the value I want.

How do i get the date from the DatePicker ContentControl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal ContentControl _
As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)
    MsgBox ContentControl.Range.Text
End Sub
```

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

Comment: Yes, let me test it at work tomorrow. The answer looks as good as yours.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me as well. There's also this resource on MSDN in case anyone is looking for more: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836891.aspx

Comment: @VincentCourtemanche the article on the link is completely useless. It hasn't got a single word on `ContentControl.Range`.

Comment: You may be looking at the wrong link? The first two words of the article are Content Controls, and that's what the article is about.