# Extract data from content controls in Word to Excel

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have a Word document that is "form-fillable", i.e. it has content control objects in it such as rich text and date picker content controls. I am looking to extract the data from specific fields into Excel. For example, every form has the project title, start date, and manager. I would like 1 row for that form with those three pieces of data. Eventually this will need to be done for a few hundred of these forms every few months, but for now I'd like to just start with one.

I envision having a button on the Excel sheet that will run VBA code to pull the data from the Word document, and populate the proper cells in the sheet. With the filepath for the Word doc being specified by the user.

I am new to VBA. How do I point my code at the right file, and then again at the specific field I need? Do I give the fields titles in the Word doc?

This is in MS Office '13

Comment: This is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823874/with-a-word-contentcontrol-datepicker-how-do-i-get-the-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application is going to have a large number of specific details which are difficult to address without the specifics.  To get started, here is some very simple code to get the Date from a drop-down in Excel from Word.

Note to work with Word, you need to create a reference to "Microsoft Word 15.0 Object Library" on the Excel side.  Tools -> References in the VBA Editor.

[image: reference addition]

When working across applications, it can help to write the VBA in Word and then move it over to Excel once you have the properties you want.

This VBA for the Excel side of the equation:

```
Sub GetDataFromWordFile()

    Dim wrd As Word.Application
    Dim file As Word.Document


    Set wrd = New Word.Application
    Set file = wrd.Documents.Open("test.docx")

    Range("A1") = file.ContentControls(1).Range.Text

    file.Close
    wrd.Quit

End Sub
```

My Word file includes a single ContentControl.  Not sure how you address the ones you want (trial and error?).

[image: Word file]

The Excel side drops the date in the right place.

[image: Excel side]

Comment: Excellent, thank you! This is what I was looking for to get started. I will try this out. Can all the code be run on the Excel file, or does the Word doc require any VBA of it's own?

Comment: @partiallyfulltime, all of the code will run on the Excel side.  No changes required on the Word side.  It can be helpful to work with the Word object model on the Word side of things when trying to get the right objects, but the final code is all on the Excel side.