# Entering data to excel with code

Tags: excel

I have an existing excel sheet with a couple hundreds of lines that I wish to write in them data that I receive from a user by an entry form of my design. Excel's data entry form cannot handle that much.

What is recommended to use for this? Is this can only be done with included VBA ([like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29524537/extract-data-from-content-controls-in-word-to-excel))?
I understand that ExcelPlus is deprecated.

Creating a new, empty sheet in the process is fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using VBA probably would be the best surgical fix to your problem, but it would also require a bit coding, and of course, it requires that you know VBA.  As an alternative, I can suggest that you just generate CSV output from your custom form in a CSV format, such that it can easily be cut and pasted into your current worksheet.  What I mean here is that the CSV output, when highlighted, should line up exactly with its target, e.g.

```
Name Age Rank
Tom  35  Senior
Mark     Mentor
Jeff 29  Junior
```

This would generate:

```
Tom, 35, Senior
Mark,,Mentor
Jeff,29,Junior
```

which when pasted into your worksheet would line up exactly.

Comment: I made a very rough entry Form in VBA. But it is limited by what it can do. If I code in Java then I could get a much powerful tool. Then I'd have to overcome the hardship of transferring data from it to Excel.

What would you use to create CSV data?

Comment: I assumed that you were using a tool over which you had some degree of control as to CSV output.  If not, then I should probably remove this answer.

Comment: As I said - I made a very basic VBA based form. I also wrote a draft in Access. I also tried a bit of HTML-JavaScript but it amounted to nothing.